# Cookies and tRPC

Tags: typescript, cookies, trpc.io

I'm having trouble understanding how to handle cookies with tRPC.

I'm confused particularly about how to send cookies back from the server, and then how to read the cookies from the res. Every SO and GitHub post I've found regarding tRPC cookies has not helped.

Here's a sample of my code so you have an idea as to where I'm at.

Feel free to ask any clarifying questions

```
// backend/index.ts

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cors());

app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(
  "/login/v1",
  trpcExpress.createExpressMiddleware({
    router: loginRouter,
    createContext: createLoginContext
  })
);
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

```
// backend/router.ts

export async function createLoginContext({req,res}: trpcExpress.CreateExpressContextOptions) {
  
  return {
    req,
    res
  }
}

export type LoginContext = trpc.inferAsyncReturnType<typeof createLoginContext>

export const loginRouter = trpc.router<LoginContext>()
.mutation('testCookies', {
  async resolve({ctx, input}):Promise<any> {
    console.log(ctx.req.cookies);
    ctx.res.cookie('I set this cookie','cooookkiiieee')
    return ??
  }
});
```

```
// client/requests.ts

const createLoginRouter = () => {
    return createTRPCClient<LoginRouter>({
      url: "http://localhost:5000/login/v1",
      headers: {
         // use universal cookie to set a cookie property? 
      }

    })
}

export const testCookiesRequest = async() => {
  const client = createLoginRouter() 
  try {
    const val = await client.mutation('testCookies')
    return val
  } catch(e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perry,

Not sure if you ever had this fixed, but if it helps, I managed to set up an express server with session cookies this way.

In your server, you need to initialize cors with credentials like this.

```js
app.use(cors({credentials: true}))
```

Then you need to add the express session to your context. You can compose your context like this. This ensures that the request coming into your server will have your session and cookie

```js
import { CreateExpressContextOptions } from '@trpc/server/adapters/express'
import { Request } from 'express'
import session from 'express-session'

type ExpressRequest = Omit<CreateExpressContextOptions, 'req'> & {
  req: Request & { session: Session }
}

export const createContext = ({
  req,
  res,
}: ExpressRequest) => {
  return {
    req,
    res
  }
}

export type Context = inferAsyncReturnType<typeof createContext>
```

And finally for some where in your app where you use trpc, set your credentials to `include`

```js
return httpBatchLink({
      url: `${getBaseUrl()}/api`,
      fetch(url, options) {
        return fetch(url, {
          ...options,
          credentials: 'include',
        })
      },
    })
```

I hope this helps.